# no such table: XXXX (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]) ... sometimes

Tags: codenameone

My mobile app built with codename one works pretty well.

But sometimes, some of my users send me "no such table: entryFoodTag (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1])" errors.

It never occurs on my own phones and my users can use the app most of the time.

Maybe it's a codename one bug ? Or some phones doesn't manage SQLite very well ?

Thank you, have a nice day !

Comment: Make sure your access to the sqlite database is from a single thread. Is this on the same device type?
There are some differences between OS's with sqlite as it's implemented natively.

Comment: Only Android so far. I think it occurs when the app is idle and try to relaunch itself.

Answer (score 0):

Android is thread safe for sqlite so this shouldn't be the problem. However, when it's in the background various things behave differently and it's possible sqlite connections no longer work.

I would recommend closing the connection to the database on the invocation of `stop()` and restoring it only when `start()` is invoked again.

Comment: I added some logs and it occurs when the app is foreground. 

I changed my code to always execute queries on the same Thread (not the EDT).

It occurs on the Xiaomi mi mix 2s of one of my users but not on my Huawai Honor 8.

Comment: new clue : the error occurs when my user download the new update from Google Play. It says the tables doesn't exists.

Comment: You need to add logs and try to get a full stack trace/error message